# while connecting to remote server java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, server, aws-sdk

while connecting to remote server getting "javax.net.socketException : unexpected end of file from server" out of 100 requests 10 requests failing 
if i sent one request no issues

please help.

Comment: It is impossible for us to diagnose this.  Start by looking at the server logs.